# Express.js live data stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, youtube-dl

I am making a app to watch the dutch television and found a way to get a watchable stream that can be used in VLC using youtube-dl.

It used the code `youtube-dl -o - "https://www.npo.nl/live/npo-1" | vlc -`

Now i want to use the data youtube-dl gives me to get a mp4 livestream with express.js

This already started logging out all the data:

```
ls    = spawn('youtube-dl',["--no-color","-q","-o","-"," www.npo.nl/live/npo-1"]);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

      console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
    });`
```

But when i tried `res.write(data.toString());` it didn't work.

Full code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   webapp.get('/watch/1', (req,res) => {

  res.setHeader('Content-Type','video/mp4');
  res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding','chunked');

    ls    = spawn('youtube-dl',["--no-color","-q","-o","-"," www.npo.nl/live/npo-1"]);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

  res.write(data.toString());
  console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});

});
```

Is there something I am missing?

By the way, `webapp` is my express app.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" - did you get any errors?  Did the page fail to load?

Comment: The page didn't load. it kept on loading instead of being a live stream.

Comment: Have you inspected the network activity?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: In your browser, you can hit F12 to load the debug tools.  There is a "network" tab that will show requests and responses.  That can show you what actually came from the server.  I'm guessing there is a good clue in that to help understand what's happening.

Comment: The biggest value is **Waiting (TTFB) 7.33s**

Comment: No response for it?  That sounds like nothing is coming from the server to the browser.  I'm not sure *how* but you can probably do something to flush the output stream without closing the connection.

Comment: ... also, I believe Express has a facility for passing streams directly to the output.

Comment: I tried flushing with `res.flush();`, i added charset headers and more but it all didn't work.

Comment: Hmm... My Express knowledge is getting close to tapped out :)  check on what features Express has (maybe middleware?) to support streaming to output?

Comment: This link looks like it will give you enough information to do what you're trying to do using piped streams: https://medium.com/@amberlamps84/oboe-js-mongodb-express-node-js-and-the-beauty-of-streams-4a90fad5414

Comment: When using `ls.stdout.pipe(res);` it will give a endless file that keeps on downloading until i stop the app. Inside of the file it looks like a mp4 file (lots of random characters). But, when i add .mp4 to the file it will still not play. The file starts with https://pastebin.com/4s55SJ8L (it was too long), does this mean anything

Comment: Didn't see your link. i will look at it.

Comment: ls.stdout.pipe(res) is looking promising ... what content-type response header are you sending?  With the information I have, that is your most likely issue now.

Comment: i used movie/mp4